# Turn of system file read buffering in Python

Tags: python, filesystems, buffer, tornado

I have my TCP server written on Tornado , Python web-framework, that receives data every 1-10 seconds. Then I need to read my file 'example.txt' on each iteration , where I store data in list format(JSON), merge my data with old data and write to file again.
There is one problem - after some time (or some times/some amount of data) , file begins caching(or buffering) , so as result I get non-relevant data from file , each time I want to read it. But file still available for writing and Python writes new, but merged with non-relevant data, to file, I can see it from modification time of file.

`open('example.txt', 'r', 0)` - doesn't help
`python -u`  - flag doesn't help
`PYTHONUNBUFFERED variable` - doesn't help
`file.flush(), os.fsync()` - doesn't help

P.S. Production server is working on CentOs.

```
def saveToFile(self, data, path):
        if os.path.exists(path) == True:
            with open(path, 'r', 0) as f:
                old = f.read()
            try:
                old = json.loads(old)
            except ValueError:
                old = {}
        else:
            old = {}

        data_to_save = dict(old.items() + data.items())


        with open(path, 'w', 0) as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(data_to_save))
```

I call this method at each new part of data I get.

Comment: What about use a memcached service?

Comment: The problem isn't what you think it is. The system isn't giving you stale data for no reason Are you opening and closing the file during each iteration? Do you have a lock in place so that two file accesses cannot happen concurrently? Please reduce your program to the smallest possible program that demonstrates the error, and copy-paste that short program into your question.

Comment: Of course , that is possible solution as we use Redis, but at this moment I need to solve this problem using files.

1) Y
2) I don't have a lock, because reading and writing a file executes line by line and files processing ends before new connection comes. I tried to set locks , but there's no difference.

Comment: @Robᵩ, what about this ?